# HTML/CSS: Copy data from form1 to form2 using JS

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I have a problem I cant seem to figure out, been looking at it for the last 2 days...

I'm testing so my JS function to copy from form1 to form2 works. And it does, partially.

If you look at the fiddle i've pasted just the necessary bits of code.

- the input type with `name="txtTitle"` gets copied from `name="hidTitle"`.
- the input type with `name="txtCount"` does not get copied from `name="hidCount"`.

But it should be working since it's basically the same code?

http://jsfiddle.net/mVfZa/7/

Comment: Your fiddle has errors... there is html in the css field. And I believe some js is missing.

Comment: you wanna name your variables more descriptively

Comment: edited fiddle..
When you press "edit" the song and count input fields should have text in them. In the fiddle, neither has. But on my computer Song-textfield gets the copied info but not the count-textfield

Comment: Your code has many errors. This issue is occurring due to an error in you `copyEditDeleteSongFormData` function in line `formUpd.fileSoundFileName.value = formDel.hidSoundeFileName.value` as it is unable to find that element. If you move this line as the last line of the function your code would work. If you check the errors in error console in any browser you would be able to see all the errors. I have removed some errors in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mVfZa/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JSFiddle - I think this is a simple mistake. you wrote 
`formDel.hidSoundeFileName` instead of `formDel.hidSoundFileName`

remove the redundant "e" and you should be fine. 
below is my working example. let me know if I missed something.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function copyEditDeleteSongFormData(formDel, formUpd) {
                formUpd.txtTitle.value = formDel.hidTitle.value;
                formUpd.fileSoundFileName.value = formDel.hidSoundeFileName.value;
                formUpd.txtCount.value = formDel.hidCount.value;
                formUpd.txtTitle.value = formDel.hidTitle.value;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="adminSong.php" method="post" name="frmNewUpdateSong" id="fUpdateSong" enctype="multipart/form-data"
              onsubmit="return verifySongDetails(this)" action="adminSong.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>New/Edit Songs</legend>
                Artist
                <br>
                <select name="cboArtist" id="ddList">
                    <option value=''></option>
                    <option value='test1'>test1</option>
                    <option value='test2'>test2</option>
                    <option value='test3'>test3</option>
                </select><br>
                Song
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="txtTitle" id="txTitle">
                <br>
                <input type="file" name="fileSoundFileName">
                <br>
                <br>
                Count
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="txtCount">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save"/>
                <input type="button" name="btnReset" value="Reset" onclick="resetNewUpdateSongFormData(this.form)"/>
                <br>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidId">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidSoundFileName">
                <br>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <br>


        <form action="#" method="post" name="frmEditDeleteSong" id="fDeleteSong" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Stored Songs</legend>
                id: <br/>
                artistid:<br/>
                title:<br/>
                sound:<br/>
                count:<br/>
                changedate:<br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidId">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidArtistId" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidTitle" value="Songtest">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidCount" value="Count123">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidSoundFileName">

                <br>
                <input type="button" name="btnEdit" value="Edit"
                       onclick="copyEditDeleteSongFormData(this.form, frmNewUpdateSong)"/>
                <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="verifyDeleteOfSong(this.form)"/>
                <br>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```